# Map in Framework 7

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, html-framework-7

I am trying to load my map in framework 7 but I am unable to do that. The error I am getting is google is undefined.

Below are my codes

JavaScript code

```
CascadingApp.onPageInit('admin', function(page) {
    initialize();
});

function initialize() {
    var map = null;
    var latlng;
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
    var options = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="map" style="height:400px; width:1200px;"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= AIzaSyAWzZ-1BPmaWKFT0du3cis82mj9Y5ljIgk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Does not load map in the page.

Comment: The google maps callback function is `initMap`, that is the function it will call once the API is loaded.  You are calling `initialize` before the API is available.

Comment: @geocodezip Am new to this would you please provide a sample code or refer me to one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add google api script`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= AIzaSyAWzZ-1BPmaWKFT0du3cis82mj9Y5ljIgk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>` in your index.html file. Currently api is present admin.html template. So when the
 admin view is load 
`CascadingApp.onPageInit('admin', function(page) {initialize();});` at that time google api is not full loaded i.e asynchronous behavior and throw error google not defined. So simply put google api in your index.html page rest is fine.
Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

I added the Google script at the bottom of my `index.html` but **without the callback function**.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

Next, in my `app.js` script, declare the variable map as global and create the following function to init the map when the page is fully loaded :

```
$$(window).on('load', function(e) {
  initMap();
});
```

Define the same `initMap` function inside `app.js` and remember set a style to map div (width and height at least).

Hope helpful to you ;-)